# What units does Plotly camera center (layout.scene.camera.center) use?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, plotly-python

In a 3D Plotly plot the camera center defaults to (0,0,0), where, as far as I understand, (0,0,0) refers to the centre of the 3D volume occupied by the plot, *not* the coordinate (0,0,0).

These values can be changed via `layout.scene.camera.center` as documented [here](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/#changing-the-focal-point-by-setting-center) and [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/scene/#layout-scene-camera-center). However, I can't work out what units are being used, nor can I find this information in the documentation.

E.g. if I change the camera center to (1,1,1), where is this in relation to my plot? From a bit of experimenting I have discovered that:

- (1,1,1) puts the camera center outside the volume occupied by my plot, but I can't figure out how far outside,
- (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) put the camera center near, but not exactly on, one of the edges of the volume occupied by the plot; sometimes it is near a corner of the volume, sometimes it is along an edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm not 100% sure that my answer relates to plotly-python, but it works that way in plotly-js so I suppose it should be the same.*

By default camera's center is set to `(0, 0, 0)`, that is the visual center of your plot. So, assuming following edge values on axes:

- x: [10, 110],
- y: [0, 50],
- z: [1, 11],

Center point will have coords of `(60, 25, 6)` (e.g. for x: `(10 + 110) / 2 == 60`).

To calculate camera coords corresponding to some `point` within your plot's axes, you can use the following formula (given example is for `x` axis, but is valid for any):

```
multiplier = 0.5 * aspectratio.x
x = ((point.x - center.x) / halfLengthOfAxisX) * multiplier
```

So, in our example, if we wanted to center the camera on point (1, 2, 3), given aspect ratio 1, we would have:

```
multiplier = 0.5
halfLengthOfAxisX = 50 // Math.abs(center.x - Math.min(x))
x = ((1 - 60) / 50) * 0.5 // -0.59
```

You mentioned that `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` puts the camera  near, but not exactly on one of the edges. That's probably caused by not taking `aspectratio` into the consideration. From what I know there is no way to retrieve it if it's calculated by Plotly (at least using Plotly.js; it could work differently in Python), so you may need to set it manually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! How are you defining `aspectratio`?

Comment: `aspectratio` is defined as the ratio of width to height; in Plotly it's located in `layout.scene`, see [ref](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-scene-aspectratio)